# php is there a bug in assigning value to variable inside if condition?

Tags: php, if-statement, variable-assignment

Please Look at this code:

```
function getVar(){
    return "some string";
}

function test1(){
    if($a = getVar()){
        echo $a;
    }
}

function test2(){
    if($a = getVar() && $b = getVar()){
        echo $a;
    }
}

//test1();
test2();
```

I think you will understand what is happening. Just try `test1()` and `test2()`

Why is `test2()` making `$a` `1` ?

Comment: In `if` conditions, you should use `==` to check for equality. `=` is for assignment.

Comment: if statements return either true or false. This is probably what is being returned.

Comment: Oh yes assignment has lower precedence than `&&`, little too sleepy atm. The question is not too bad to deserve many downvotes, though OP should add the code to the question.

Comment: @jeff: `if` statements don't return anything.

Comment: @Mark I agree 100% but I deliberately used the term 'returns' instead of evaluate because it made more sense with the code supplied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, the code is doing the following : `if ($a = (getVar() && $b=getVar()))`. There is no error on this. `"some string" && "some string" == true`

You can learn about [the operator precedence in PHP in the doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php).

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: It would be better if you added how to correct the code. I just needed to put assignments in brackets to assign returned values to variables $a and $b.

Answer (score 2):

It's essentially running this:

```
<?php

function getVar(){
    return "some string";
}

function test1(){
    if($a = getVar()){
        echo $a;
    }
}

function test2(){
    if($a = (getVar() && $b=getVar())){
        echo $a;
    }
}

//test1();
test2();


?>
```

Notice the extra brackets I added.

`getVar()` returns a truthy value. When it's evaluated in the context of a boolean (via `&&`) it's cast to a bool, so the whole expression returns `true`. `echo` just displays this as `1` for whatever reason, but you can `var_dump` it instead to see its type.

Comment: Didn`t get. Is there any way I can make this work. I need to get assigned value $a and $b inside if in test2

Comment: If you want both `$a` and `$b` to have the value `"some string"` then move your brackets to wrap them appropriately; `if(($a=getVar() && ($b=getVar()))`. But it's bad form to assign variables inside an if statement.

Comment: Too many brackets.. I didn't even do that right. `if(($a=getVar()) && ($b=getVar()))` (but again, I don't recommend it!!)

Answer (score 0):

In test2() ,

```
$a = (getVar() && $b = getVar())
```

getvar() , returns a string so it's assigned to $b , then it's redued to ,

```
$a = (getVar() && $b)

   then get var() return a string so it has a value,
```

then `$a = (some value && $b)`

then what && do is , it checks for booleon value , both side has boolean true , so it return boolean true and assign to $a. it means $b has 1.